# Declare same template class as friend inside the template class?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, friend

Consider the following:

```
template<std::integral T>
class Integer {
  T value;

  template<std::integral T2>
  friend class Integer;

 public:
  template<std::integral T2>
  friend bool operator==(Integer<T> x, Integer<T2> y) {
    return x.value == y.value;
  }
};
```

the `Integer` class defines the friend `operator==` to compare other entities with different template parameters and declares the template `Integer` class as the friend class.

But when I compare two objects with different template parameters:

```
Integer<int> x;
Integer<long> y;
x == y;
```

[Clang accepts it but GCC and MSVC reject it with](https://godbolt.org/z/1bY5n5Pba):

```
<source>:11:25: error: 'long int Integer<long int>::value' is private within this context
   11 |     return x.value == y.value;
      |                       ~~^~~~~
```

This surprised me a bit. In my opinion, it should be well-formed, because `operator==` is a friend of `Integer<int>`, and `Integer<long>` is a friend of `Integer<int>`, so `operator==` should also have permission to access the member of `Integer<long>`.

So Which compiler should I trust?

### Update

This is [CWG1699](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1699).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[class.friend]**
>
> [10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.friend#10) Friendship is neither inherited nor transitive. [Example 8:
>
> ```
> class A {
>   friend class B;
>   int a;
> };
>
> class B {
>   friend class C;
> };
>
> class C  {
>   void f(A* p) {
>     p->a++;         // error: C is not a friend of A despite being a friend of a friend
>   }
> };
>
> class D : public B  {
>   void f(A* p) {
>     p->a++;         // error: D is not a friend of A despite being derived from a friend
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> — end example]

Instantiating `Integer<int>` "injects" the following function:

```
template<std::integral T2>
  friend bool operator==(Integer<int> x, Integer<T2> y)
```

Now, while `Integer<int>` could be a friend of `Integer<long>`, the `operator==` that gets added **is not**. It's only a friend of `Integer<int>` at most. So it cannot access a private member of `Integer<long>`. The same analysis works in the other direction too, of course (not that it matters much, since a rewritten candidate is considered a poorer match<sup>1</sup>).

If you want mixed comparisons, you need symmetry. Both arguments must be unknown `Integer` specializations (with their own template parameter), and the class template needs to befriend the operator.

Unfortunately, that also means that the operator can't be defined inline (since every instantiation will "inject" and redefine it). So this is the viable solution:

```
template<std::integral T>
class Integer {
  T value{};

 public:
    template<std::integral T2, std::integral T3>
    friend bool operator==(Integer<T2> x, Integer<T3> y);
};

template<std::integral T2, std::integral T3>
bool operator==(Integer<T2> x, Integer<T3> y) {
    return x.value == y.value;
}
```

---

1 [over.match.best.general/2.8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match.best.general#2.8) - *"... a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function F2 if ... F2 is a rewritten candidate ([over.match.oper]) and F1 is not"*

Answer (score 2):

The friend of your friend is not your friend.

```
#include <concepts>

template<std::integral T>
class Integer {
  T value;

  template<std::integral T2>
  friend class Integer;

 public:
  template<std::integral T2>
  bool operator==(Integer<T2> y) const {
    return value == y.value;
  }
};

int main() {
  Integer<int> x;
  Integer<long> y;
  return x == y;
}
```

this works, as the member `operator==` is befriended.

Another approach is using a private subclass accessor "key" object:

```
struct GetValue {
  template<std::integral T2>
  T operator()(Integer<T2> const& self)const{
    return self.value;
  }
};
```

as a member class, it *does* gain access to the friendship of its containing class.

Once we have this, then `operator==` is simple and can remain a free friend function:

```
template<std::integral T2>
friend bool operator==(Integer<T> x, Integer<T2> y) {
  return GetValue{}(x) == GetValue{}(y);
}
```

the ability to make `GetValue` "key" objects, which `operator==` has, gives the ability to read the value of different `Integer<T2>`s via the `GetValue` object.

This isn't a great [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) answer; @storyteller did a good job there.  This is merely two clean techniques to solve the problem.

Comment: I think the third solution can be to declare a private `equal` function inside `Integer` to access the `value` of other `Integer` type, and then call `x.equal(y)` in `operator==` function, I have seen [many such techniques](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/ranges#L4082) in libstdc++'s `<ranges>` implementation. BTW, I really like your second approach.

Comment: @康桓瑋 They "key" private struct trick has a lot of uses.  For example, you can use it to enable `make_shared` to work with otherwise private constructors.  An instance of a "key" object lets you pass permissions around like a value.